# Не понимаю роль переменной в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nak2AOrieTA 
`Тайм-код 20:11`
Не понимаю, как движок определяет, что такое переменная faceRight, ведь тип данных у неё bool, а не тип данных движка, типа GameObject и т.п. То есть, как мне кажется, при записи
`if (moveX > 0 && !faceRight)` написано, что если движение направлено вправо и false, то. Типа, не faceRight это false, ок, а как движок определяет, что переменная faceRight отвечает за направление нашего персонажа. Какую роль здесь играет эта переменная, объясните по подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Философы раньше: "Почему солнце светит? Что происходит с душой после смерти? Есть ли край вселенной?". Философы сейчас: "Не понимаю существование переменной в коде"

Comment: Это понятно, но я с таким же успехом могу задать переменной имя ```jump``` и приравнять её к ```true```, это не значит то, что когда я буду к ней обращаться, она будет вызывать прыжок. Я вот этот момент не до понимаю.

Comment: А можно сразу ответ, мне не понятно ничего?

Comment: А при чем тут наследование? Там создается простой метод `flip()`, который задает значение переменной и меняет персонажа. При чем тут вообще движок?

Comment: Следуя этой же логике тебя должен был смутить float.

Comment: если вам непонятно ничего, начните не с изучения Unity, а с основ программирования и ООП, можно на базе того же C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А это не движок определяет.

В данном видеоуроке faceRight - это свойство обьекта, которое разработчик сам добавил для указания и определения, в какую сторону смотрит игровой обьект. Движок никаком образом на это не влияет. А вот разработчик влияет, реализуя проверки и изменяя при помощи метода flip(). В котором меняет это свойство, заодно производя нужные манипуляции уже с игровым обьектом через игровой движок.

Еще раз - это всего лишь свойство, добавленное разработчиков для определения направления, куда смотрит игровой обьект. Управляет значением этого свойства не движок, а сам разработчик в коде.

Comment: кстати, видеоурок довольно старенький, сейчас в Unity много чего добавили и изменили, в том числе новый Input System и другие возможности.

Comment: Ну это же просто булевая переменная, каким образом то? Это тру или фолс, как это работает-то?

Comment: Что непонятно то? Как работают свойства в классе, как наследование в ООП работает или что?
еще раз - это свойство, переменная, добавленная в свой код для удобства определения, в какую сторону смотрит персонаж.
Он в коде ему ставит значение true - считая что персонаж смотрит вправо. Поставил false - смотрит влево. Конструкция faceRight = !faceRight лишь меняет значение этой перменной, с true на false, с false на true. В методе update он просто проверяет его, чтобы определить, надо ли повернуть персонажа или он уже смотрит в нужную сторону. Все, это все что делает эта перменная.

Comment: Так, то есть, код можно написать и без неё, это чисто для визуального удобства прописано?

Comment: Для удобства, ускорения и упрощения проверок

Comment: А если переменной не будет, ничего не поменяется? Код будет также работать?

Comment: Вам явно нужно подтянуть знания основ программирование, ООП и алгоритмизации... 
Конечно поменяется, вам даже компилятор не даст скомпилировать код, так как эта переменная используется в нескольких местах. Если же удалить все упоминание, ну тогда код просто перестанет логически выполнять то, что задумано и будет работать некорректно. Можно обойтись без этой переменной, как я уже упоминал, но тогда код усложнится за счет более сложных проверок вместо банальной проверки на True/False